Jest custom matcher not recognized by IntelliJ
I have created a custom matcher with Jest named toHaveSameText the tests are running fine from both command line and from IntelliJ, However, IntelliJ editor is showing the matcher in red and project reports compilation error. If I hover over the error in intelliJ, I get following error on hover: TS2339: Property toHaveSameText does not exist on type Assertion<string> but If I run test the custom matcher works as expected.

Here are various files I created to created my custom matcher.
setup.d.ts
type OwnMatcher<Params extends unknown[]> = (
    this: jest.MatcherContext,
    actual: unknown,
    ...params: Params
) => jest.CustomMatcherResult

//@ts-ignore
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R, T> {
      toHaveSameText(actual: string, expected: string): T
    }
    interface ExpectExtendMap {
      // Here, we're describing the call signature of our
      // matcher for the "expect.extend()" call.
      toHaveSameText: OwnMatcher<[actual: string, expected: string]>
    }
  }
}

setup.js
import { expect, afterEach } from 'vitest';
import { Assertion, assert } from 'chai';
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

expect.extend({ toHaveSameText(actual, expected) {
    let test = new Assertion(actual, expected, assert.equal, true);
    test.assert(actual.replace(/\s/g, '') === expected.replace(/\s/g, ''),
        'expected #{this} to equal #{exp}',
        'expected #{this} to not equal #{act}',
        expected,
        actual,
        true);
    return { pass: true };
  }
});

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});

In vite.config.js I have setupFiles: ['@testing-library/jest-dom', './test/setup.js'],
I also tried adding "include": ["./test/setup.d.ts"] in my tsconfig.json, but it didn't work.
Am I missing something for IntelliJ to recognize the custom matcher.

the error comes from the Typescript compiler, not from the IDE. It must be a typescript configuration issue. Do you have a sample project you can share that reproduces it?

Yes it is the typescript compiler that is complaining. Because if I add a //@ts-ignore in the line before intelliJ doesn't complain. But what I don't understand is why does typescript compiler not have issue when I'm building the project or running tests. I will try to see if I can move this to a sample project to share.
